# Adding Xaml Shape/Path Programmaticallyin .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am designing an app for Windows 8 using XAML and VB but think this problem may well apply to Silverlight and WPF, also.

I can create a shape in a drawing app and then save as XAML to get the necessary code to recreate this shape in the XAML code editor in Visual Studio 2012.

For instance the following produces a test shape:

```
    <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Gray"
    Data="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100"  Grid.Row="1"/>
```

I would like to be able to create this shape programmatically using the info from the Data attribute.

So far, I have looked into this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx), which explains the PathGeometry Class. However, it seems to use a different method.

What I'm asking is if there's a way to take the Data attribute and paste it into a property to create the shape in VB. Or if there's another way to do this that I'm missing.

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class:

```
var path = XamlReader.Load("<Path Stroke=\"Black\" Fill=\"Gray\" Data=\"M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100\" Grid.Row=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" />");
Canvas.Children.Add(path as UIElement);
```

Just make sure you include the default namespace in the XAML snippet you are loading. `Canvas` is a `Grid` in my page that I'm adding the `Path` to.

Comment: Thank you, Damir, Unfortunately that class isn't available in Windows Store apps. I've found a link where someone else discusses this problem: [LINK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/b1aef630-bad2-41cc-b413-be6b12548e90)

Comment: @Sparked Did you click on the link? Just make sure you're using the right namespace: it's 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup' in WinRT, not `System.Windows.Markup` like in WPF. I wrote a small working sample to make sure it works before posting the answer.

Comment: It works. Thank you, @Damir, that's a big help. As you say, I was using the wrong namespace.